# Why CR LF is changed to LF in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, io, language-lawyer

In Windows when you read characters `\r\n` from the file(or stdin) in text mode, `\r` gets deleded and you only read `\n`.

Is there a standard according to which it should be so?

Could I be sure that it will be true for any compiler on Windows? Will others platform-specifics character combinations will replaced by `\n` on those platforms too?

I use [this code](http://ideone.com/2LKgWW) to generate the input and use [this code](http://ideone.com/0XTfH6) to read it.  The results are [here](http://ideone.com/vi74IV). You may note few missed `\r`'s

Comment: @JohnDibling  What for?

Comment: Because it might depend on exactly what `read`/`fscanf`/`operator<<` function you call.

Comment: @JohnDibling, [input generator](http://ideone.com/2LKgWW), how I read from it: http://ideone.com/0XTfH6 . [Result](http://ideone.com/vi74IV). You may note few missed `\r`'s

Comment: For the confused, the tag `[language-lawyer]` matters for this question.  This question isn't about "why does it happen" but rather "by what clause in the standard is this thing that happens justified?"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, this comes from compatibility with C. In C text streams, lines are terminated by a newline character.  This is the internal representation of the text stream as seen by the program. The I/O library converts between the internal representation and some external one.

The internal representation is platform-independent, whereas there are different platform-specific conventions for text. That's the point of having a text mode in the stream library; portable text manipulating programs can be written which do not have to contain a pile of `#ifdef` directives to work on different platforms, or build their own platform-independent text abstraction.

It so happens that the internal representation for C text streams matches the native Unix representation of text files, since the C language and its library originated on Unix.  For portability of C programs to other platforms, the text stream abstraction was added which makes text files on non-Unix system look like Unix text files.

In the ISO/IEC 9899:1999 standard ("C99"), we have this:

> *7.19.2 Streams*
>
> [...]
>
> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into lines, each line
>   consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the
>   last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined. **Characters
>   may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to conform to differing
>   conventions for representing text in the host environment. Thus, there need not be a one-to-one correspondence between the characters in a stream and those in the external
>   representation.**

Bold emphasis mine.  C++ streams are defined in terms of C streams.  There is no explanation of text versus binary mode in the C++ standard, except for a table which maps various stream mode flag combinations to strings suitable as mode arguments to `fopen`.

Comment: Your answer shows the reason why it was made so well, but I would also find the rule (standard) where it's claimed if possible. I've tried to search '\n' in C++11 draft but didn't find any relevant info

Comment: You want exact chapter and verse citations?

Comment: Seems 5.2.2 2-3 should be the answer (according to n1256)

Comment: @RiaD:  Note that the standard Kaz is referring to here (n1256) is the C Standard, not the C++ Standard.

Comment: @JohnDibling, actually I've metioned them

Comment: @RiaD:  Oh, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: @RiaD Surprisingly, there is nothing in the C++ standard (last C++11 draft I'm looking at). C++ streams have a `binary` mode but it's not really described. All they do is map the various C++ stream modes into `fopen` flags! So, the specification of text streams is assumed to come from the C standard.  Someone reading the C++ standard is expected to be familiar with C streams, or to read the C standard to brush up on them.

Comment: @Kaz §1.1.2 explicitly says c++ based on C

Comment: Oh, the C standard makes it clear. In the C99 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) just look at "7.19.2 Streams". *A text stream is an ordered sequence of lines, each line consisting of zero or more characters, plus a terminating new-line character.*

Comment: @RiaD It is true that C++ is based on C, and includes the C standard by normative reference. But from that it doesn't follow that there is never any redundancy. For instance, the C++ standard defines the `if` statement, even though C has such a statement.

Comment: @Kaz:  The C++ standard also says somewhere (can't cite now) that in case there is any conflict between the two standards, the C++ wins.  As for *why* some things are defined identically in both, well I have no idea.

Comment: Now we're gettin' somewhere.

Comment: C++ gets the binary/text mode behavior from C because `basic_filebuf<>::open()` behavior is defined in terms of C's `fopen()` function (see C++11 27.9.1.4).